# Array in Constructor

Tags: c++, oop

What happens in the following code?

I guess it doesn't work since I get a segmentation fault if I want to add something to the b array, but what exactly did I do here?

Is there no way of specifying the size of an array inside the constructor?

```
class A {
  public:
   A() {
      b[3];
   }
  private:
    B b[];
};
```

Comment: What is this code attempting to do?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that that's even valid syntax; never knew you could write the horrid `T ar[]` outside of a function parameter list.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: If I recall, it's a common extension to allow it as the last member of a type, so you can allocate with `malloc(sizeof(A)+3)` and pretend the `b` is an array of `B[4]`.

Comment: @Mooing: Yuk!??! Anyway, no wonder I can't find it in the standards. It's strictly an implementation extension, then?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, what's the yuk for? It used to be extremely difficult to do trailing arrays in standard C++ (it's a little easier now that we have alignof and others, though still far less elegant than the extension).

Comment: @avakar: As far as I know it's a C99 feature. It isn't in any version of C++, though.

Comment: @celtschk, oh, is it standard C99? Thanks, I didn't know that; I always thought it's a pure extension.

Comment: @avakar: Yuk because that sounds abhorrent!

Comment: Wait... are all the answers wrong? `T a[]` isn't the same as `T *a` in this context!

Comment: @avakar the yuk is for the idea of trailing arrays in itself, imo.

Comment: @avakar: Yes, see e.g. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp9.bg.doc/language_ref/strct.htm#flexible

Comment: @avakar: Correct, in this context, `T a[]` is a zero-length array.  There's lots of information about it on the internet.

Comment: Just browsed C99; it's called "flexible array member". I'd love to see that in C++; I don't find it yucky at all, it can save you some dynamic allocations.

Comment: Actually I'd prefer Extended Pascal's schema types to be added to C++. It would achieve even more flexibility without sacrificing type safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B b[]` here is a "[flexible array member](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.bg.doc/language_ref/strct.htm)", a non-standard extension in your compiler (taken from C99) that allows you to declare an unbounded array as the last member in a type. It's only of use when allocating your object the old-fashioned C way (when you pad your argument to `malloc` to make space for the array), and ought to be avoided. In this case, you *haven't* allocated any extra memory for the array, so in your constructor body when you're trying to access something that occurs 3 'elements' past this nothingness, you're invoking UB. I'll ignore the extension for the rest of my answer, as it really has no place in C++ code.

> Is there no way of specifying the size of an array inside the constructor?

No, there isn't.

Array bounds must be known at compile-time, so there is no case where you know more in your ctor body than you do in the class definition; you are required to write the dimension in the member's declaration itself:

```
class A {
    B b[3];
};
```

If the dimension is a run-time quantity in your program, you'll need to instead store a pointer and, in your constructor, point it at a dynamic block of memory:

```
class A {
  public:
   A() : b(new B[3]) {}
  ~A() { delete[] b; }
  private:
    B* b;   // same as `B b[]`! but far clearer
};
```

Instead, though, I suggest a `std::vector`:

```
class A {
  public:
   A() : b(3) {}
  private:
    std::vector<B> b;
};
```

Comment: `B *b` is not the same as `B b[]` in this context.

Comment: Would be +1 for an excellent explanation, but for the factually incorrect statements in the first paragraph.

Comment: @avakar, @Rob: Learned something new today! My answer should be complete now. `

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Using operator `new`: `b = new B[3];`. Declare `b` as `B *b` for that.
Of course, you need to `delete[]` it in the destructor.

But a better way would be using `std::vector` instead of the array, and then you don't need to worry about preallocating memory.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't support any types with size determined at runtime. Therefore you have only the options to determine the array size at compile time (possible through a non-type template parameter) or move the array out of the object by making `b` a pointer and allocating memory for it with `new` (or, better, let the standard library do that for you by using a `vector`).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible - what would you expect sizeof(A) to evaluate to?! If you really need such functionality, use dynamic allocation, i.e. a private member variable B *b, b(new B[3]) in the constructors initializer list, and delete[] b; in the destructor.